# Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation

Tags: c++, opengl

I try to build this Tutorial: [this one](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/)

with the following code in window.cpp:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GL/glfw.h>

//Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include <common/shader.hpp>

int main( void )
{
// Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

// Initialize GLEW
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle( "Tutorial 02" );

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

// Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f);

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );


static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

do{

    // Clear the screen
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // From index 0 to 3 -> 1 triangle

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

// Cleanup VBO
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

return 0;
}
```

`

And the following code in the shader.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "shader.hpp"

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){

// Create the shaders
GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
std::string VertexShaderCode;
std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
        VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    VertexShaderStream.close();
}

// Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
std::string FragmentShaderCode;
std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
        FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    FragmentShaderStream.close();
}



GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
int InfoLogLength;



// Compile Vertex Shader
printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

// Check Vertex Shader
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL,
&VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);




// Compile Fragment Shader
printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

// Check Fragment Shader
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL,
&FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);




// Link the program
fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

// Check the program
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);


glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

return ProgramID;
}
```

But when is run the code in debug mode ( i copied the full code from the Tutorial Files) my programm starts, but than it opens a errorwindow of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express, the window contains the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

My Debug Console show the following errors/outputs:

```
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Domenik\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Engine\Debug\Engine.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Domenik\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Engine\Debug\glew32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xcfc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Engine.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1198) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x538) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xdb0) has exited with code -805306369 (0xcfffffff).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1370) has exited with code -805306369 (0xcfffffff).
The program '[2624] Engine.exe: Native' has exited with code -805306369 (0xcfffffff).
```

my stack contains this:

```
00000000()  
Engine.exe!main()  Line 54 + 0x12 bytes C++
Engine.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x19 bytes   C
Engine.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 371   C
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

I had read that the pointer NULL (it find it´s use 4 times in the shader.cpp) can crash the programm if it is to often in use. That sounds so, that i can change them all to 0 or 0L but this don´t fix it.

Comment: Changing the value of NULL is a silly idea that won't solve anything. What is wrong is the code, not the value of NULL. You need to debug the code and figure out why a certain pointer is null *and* attempted to be dereferenced.

Comment: You called into a `NULL` function pointer.

Comment: the pointer always is in use in this part of code: glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL); glShaderSource have the following variables: shader, count, string, lenght; the spezification says: **The number of strings in the array is specified by count. If length is NULL, each string is assumed to be null terminated.**

Comment: Forgot to mention, I've also seen stack traces like this when there is stack corruption.  The return address gets replaced with `0` and when you get to the `ret` instruction...  It looks the same as calling into  `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really see how you are having this problem.
But you may download the the source code from that site.
Run it and compare to your own code.

Comment: I tried that with the the projekt configuration file of the site and it works, looks like i have an fail in my projektconfiguration.

Thank you ;)